# Strange issue in page speed test in wordpress site

Tags: performance, wordpress

i have a strange problem!

My site score at "tools.pingdom.com/fpt" is 99 which is really great and i have done a lot of work to get that. so, i installed a plugin "Google Language Translator" and did a test again but the score drop down to 76!! Please see the screen shots
[Before](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ivzqk8.jpg) and [After](http://oi60.tinypic.com/29f6yiq.jpg)

Also, i did combined and minified all js and css files into my main theme without any problems but the problem still remains.

Now when i deactivate the plugin the score goes back to 99!.

Would you guys please help?

My site is www.elhafez.com and now the plugin is deactivate.

Thanks

Comment: With the plugin enabled ("After" pic), a number of separate CSS files are clearly being downloaded.  Are those your CSS files, or CSS files that the Google plugin may be downloading?  If the later, it is outside of your control.

Comment: The plugin has only 2 CSS and 4 JS files by original. I did combined all the CSS files into my main theme "style" and too combined the JS into 2 files (one of them is admin.js). now i suppose the plugin only separate 1 new JS file. i can't believe that could drop down the score!

Comment: The "After" screenshot shows style.css, chosen.css, woocommerce.css, bootstrap.css and probably more as the image is cut off.

Comment: Thank you for interesting .. I'll activate the plugin now to let you see

Comment: OK, i activate it and the score down to 77. You see the total requests is 78 ?. it was 72 without the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is no specific answer but you can fix some speed performance.

1- i fixed the "Parallelize downloads across hostnames" by creating 2 sub-domains and added them as a generic CND in W3TC plugin.

2- Combined the plugin JavaScript into 1 file and moved the CSS files into main theme style.css

3- There are many code errors like Duplicate ID's and missing end tags, etc .. i fixed them Manually.

So, after all i raised the page score from 77 to 92 with CloudFlare activated.

However, the plugin is great and really useful and it doesn't effect the overall page speed, only the page speed rank and HTML validation if you care about that.

Thank you all.